# Using CommandLineParser to specify multiple inputs of the same type

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I want to use the [CommandLineParser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) package to build a utility that can specify an arbitrary number of file paths on the command line.  From my current understanding of this package, the canonical method of doing so is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Enumerable list of files
/// </summary>
[Option('i', "input", HelpText = "Input file(s) to process", Separator =',')]
public IEnumerable<string>Input { get; set; }
...
// Process the input file paths
foreach(var path in Input)
{
    ...
}
```

Which requires a command line that looks like:

```
MyProgram -i c:\path\to\first\file1.txt,c:\path\to\second\file2.txt,c:\path\to\third\file3.txt
```

But what I really want is a command line that looks like this:

```
MyProgram -i c:\path\to\first\file1.txt ^
          -i c:\path\to\second\file2.txt ^
          -i c:\path\to\third\file3.txt
```

(Note that the ^ character is the windows command line continuation char)

Although I'd be happy with:

```
MyProgram -i c:\path\to\first\file1.txt ^
             c:\path\to\second\file2.txt ^
             c:\path\to\third\file3.txt
```

Is there currently anyway to achieve what I want with the CommandLineParser package?  I am not well versed in package so I may have overlooked something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my ignorance I didn't realize that the default separator for enumerable options is in fact the space character.  So that if I had left the definition as:

```
/// <summary>
/// Enumerable list of files
/// </summary>
[Option('i', "input", HelpText = "Input file(s) to process")]
public IEnumerable<string>Input { get; set; }
```

Then out of the box the CommandLineParser would support:

```
MyProgram -i c:\path\to\first\file1.txt ^
             c:\path\to\second\file2.txt ^
             c:\path\to\third\file3.txt
```

But I also found the reported issue of [Separator does not override Space](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/issues/537) which suggests preprocessing the command line.  This would allow me to turn my preferred format of:

```
MyProgram -i c:\path\to\first\file1.txt ^
          -i c:\path\to\second\file2.txt ^
          -i c:\path\to\third\file3.txt
```

Into

```
MyProgram -i c:\path\to\first\file1.txt ^
             c:\path\to\second\file2.txt ^
             c:\path\to\third\file3.txt
```

Before handing it over to the CommandLineParser itself.

Answer (score -1):

Commandlineparser **only allows you to set properties** and still forces you to write the code that actually call the method passing as input your list of paths.

[UltraMapper.CommandLine](https://maurosampietro.github.io/UltraMapper.CommandLine/) **allows you to call methods directly** from commandline passing as many input parameters as you want.

I released **UltraMapper.CommandLine** as an open source project on github a few days ago.
[Check it out](https://maurosampietro.github.io/UltraMapper.CommandLine/), it might be helpful on your next project!

Comment: A downvote for coding, providing for free and maintaining a much better library to fullfills your needs? Ah the internet.. Anyway you can also avoid the dispatching code with UltraMapper.CommandLine. Saves you a ton of boilerplate. Cheers

Comment: I suspect that you are down voted because your answer doesn't actually answer my question, and has all the appearances of shameless self promotion of your own project.

Comment: I coded UltraMapper.CommandLine specifically to overcome the limitations of CommandLineParser. I used my library for years now and I think it can help other people, that’s why I published for free on GitHub. If it can help someone I’m happy.